# BeautifulSoup HTML Parsing using regex

Tags: html, regex, parsing, beautifulsoup, screen-scraping

I'm trying to parse four HTML pages from IMDB.com. I would like to extract all of the IMDB ID's from each listing (this can be found within the HTML code, and looks something like this: href="/title/tt0080684/" title="Star Wars: Episode V - The Empire Strikes Back (1980)" But I can't seem to get my regex below to work...is it something wrong with the regex or the syntax for beautifulsoup? Thank you!

```
import urllib2
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re, json

for start_num in ('1', '2', '3', '4'):
   response = urllib2.urlopen('http://www.imdb.com/search/title?at=0&genres=sci_fi&sort=user_rating&start='+ start_num +'&title_type=feature')
   html_doc = response.read()
   soup = BeautifulSoup(html_doc, "html.parser")

   for movie in soup.find_all(re.compile('\"href=\"/title/\"')):
      print(tag.name)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using the `find_all()` with a regular expression incorrectly. If you want `BeautifulSoup` to check the `href` attribute values against a regular expression, you need to provide an `href` keyword argument with a regular expression as a value:

```
for movie in soup.find_all(href=re.compile(r'/title/')):
    print(tag.name)
```

Answer (score 0):

I guess you want to get the  tag and its content,which is the movie name.The regular expression was wrong (there is no quotes on the href left).you can try this one:

```
re.compile('href=\"/title/\"')
```

I hope it can work.

Comment: oops, re.compile('href=\"/title/')